# removing values from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, subset

Good morning. I have some nested dictionaries with multiple items per key. I need to extract only the pairs that include items that only have 'ans' and 'val' pairs, if the item includes 'ans', 'type','value' etc then i want to remove it. an example of the dictionary i have and the expected output are below.
Any advice is welcome, thanks so much

**data**

```
dict_i_have = {
    "x19": [
        {
            "ans": "Enter number",
            "type": "number",
            "value": "input_val",
            "validators": [
                {"dype": "int", "invalid": "Enter number between 0 and 100", "min": 0, "max": 100},
                {"vtype": "no", "message": "Please enter a value"},
            ],
        },
        {"ans": "One year or less", "val": "-10"},
        {"ans": "Do not know", "val": "1"},
        {"ans": "Other", "val": "3"},
    ],
    "x20": [
        {
            "ans": "Enter number",
            "type": "number",
            "value": "input_val",
            "validators": [
                {"dype": "int", "invalid": "Enter number between 0 and 50", "min": 0, "max": 50},
                {"vtype": "no", "message": "Please enter a value"},
            ],
        },
        {"ans": "Six months or less", "val": "10"},
    ],
}
```

**expected output**

```
dict_i_want = {'x19': [{'ans': 'One year or less', 'val': '-10'},
                       {'ans': 'Do not know', 'val': '1'},
                       {'ans': 'Other', 'val': '3'}],
               'x20': [{'ans': 'Six months or less', 'val': '10'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite literally filter your list of dicts to those that have exactly two keys, with both key values you're interested in.

```
dict_i_want = dict()
for key, values in dict_i_have.items():
     subdicts = [d for d in values if len(d) == 2 and 'ans' in d and 'val' in d]
     dict_i_want[key] = subdicts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below simple solution for the problem,

```
    dict_i_have = {
        "x19": [
            {
                "ans": "Enter number",
                "type": "number",
                "value": "input_val",
                "validators": [
                    {"dype": "int", "invalid": "Enter number between 0 and 100", "min": 0, "max": 100},
                    {"vtype": "no", "message": "Please enter a value"},
                ],
            },
            {"ans": "One year or less", "val": "-10"},
            {"ans": "Do not know", "val": "1"},
            {"ans": "Other", "val": "3"},
        ],
        "x20": [
            {
                "ans": "Enter number",
                "type": "number",
                "value": "input_val",
                "validators": [
                    {"dype": "int", "invalid": "Enter number between 0 and 50", "min": 0, "max": 50},
                    {"vtype": "no", "message": "Please enter a value"},
                ],
            },
            {"ans": "Six months or less", "val": "10"},
        ],
    }
    
# Actual Solution starts here
    for key1 in dict_i_have:
        for val in dict_i_have[key1]:
            if len(val) > 2 :
                dict_i_have[key1].remove(val)
                
    print(dict_i_have)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_i_have = {
    # elided for brevity
}

dict_i_want = {
    key: [
        {"ans": q["ans"], "val": q["val"]} for q in questions if "val" in q
    ]
    for (key, questions) in dict_i_have.items()
}
print(dict_i_want)
```

Or if you want to keep references to the original dicts instead of copying them into new ones,

```
dict_i_want = {
    key: [q for q in questions if set(q) == {"ans", "val"}]
    for (key, questions) in dict_i_have.items()
}
print(dict_i_want)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dict `keys` function can get the keys in the dict.
Then compare it with `{"ans", "val"}` to filter out the unwanted dict.

```py
for key in dict_i_have.keys():
    dict_i_have[key] = [item for item in dict_i_have[key] if set(item.keys()) == {'ans', 'val'}]
```

Comment: Using `list()` is not a good idea. The order of dict keys is not necessarily guaranteed.

Comment: Good point, I have changed `list` to `set`. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You're also overwriting `dict_i_have`, when the OP wants a new dict.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP wants a new dict or not. But it is not very important.